# Is there a way to make a For Loop on a list begin its loop(iterate) at the second element of the list(skipping the first element)?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Big Picture: I have a separate function that inserts elements unto list 'a' and I need a for loop to make sure those inserted/inputted/appended elements have their data organized for a different function. Basically, I need the first two element in the sublist paired with the first two element of the sublist next to it(as shown by 'b' and 'c')...for every following sublist. This is so that there are two points to draw a line on a canvas.

Specific Picture: In order to do that, I need a way for the for loop to iterate starting from both the first element and the second element. And then I have to use the results of the for loop for the formation of my lines (as shown by g). I'm sorry if this seems confusing.

I think I can actually go through this by simply making a new list composed of everything besides the first input, making two for loops and using the results from the two for loops to input into the line widget, but I need to make sure there's no way to do this with just one for loop.

Here are some things I've been doing:

```
a = [[366, 408, 'Help'], [143, 99, 'Me'], [695, 140, 'Please']]

x1 = a[0][0]
y1 = a[0][1]
x2 = a[1][0]
y2 = a[1][1]


x2 = a[1][0]
y2 = a[1][1]
x3 = a[2][0]
y3 = a[2][1]

b = [x1, y1, x2, y2]

c = [x2, y2, x3, y3]

#print b
#print c

def draw_a_line(event):
    for d in a:
         e = d[0]
         f = d[1]
         for i in a[1:2]:
            print i
         h = a[1][0]
         #print e
         #print f
         g=[e,f, ?, ?]
```

Comment: just wanted to point out that `a[1:2]` is the same as writing `a[1]`

Comment: how about iterating over the indexes (range) of the size of the list, then you can use that index to grab the next one as well

Comment: This is really hard to understand, please consider spending some time to make it clearer.

Comment: Please show us what you expect for output.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. Thanks for pointing that out. Been really confused with lists and for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access two elements of your list `a` in one step of the loop, you can create two new iterators and advance one by one step. See itertools [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) for more info.

`import itertools
x, y = itertools.tee(a, 2)
next(y)
for p in zip(x,y): print(p)`

and `p` is sequentially equal to:

`([366, 408, 'Help'], [143, 99, 'Me'])
([143, 99, 'Me'], [695, 140, 'Please'])`

so you can get both point coordinates in the same step.